# Do DNS servers communicate with the IP you have done the lookup?

Tags: networking, dns

As mentioned in the title I would like to understand if the DNS servers send a ping or something like that to the IP which the lookup was done, I would like to know this to find a way to know when my domain is resolved.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure - but my knowledge is that your communication with the DNS server is purely between you and the DNS server. Your PC sends a DNS query, the DNS server returns the answer, and thats that. If you open the URL on a web browser - all that process is automated, and then the browser attempted to connect to it straight away. But the DNS server itself is not aware if the IP address corresponding to the server is alive or not (and is not tasked to do so - unless that DNS server somehow has the feature to check whether the IP is alive or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I would like to understand if the DNS servers send a ping or something like that to the IP which the lookup was done**

No, in simple terms, a DNS server receives a DNS enquiry packet from a DNS client and returns a DNS response packet.

The DNS service itself makes no use of `ping` (either ICMP echo requests or other varieties of ping).

> **I would like to know this to find a way to know when my domain is resolved.**

This cannot be done.

The "owner" of example.com cannot tell if someone elsewhere on the planet executed an `nslookup www.example.com`

DNS responses are cached.

The DNS service never attempts to notify the domain "owner" of lookups.

---

If you, or others, are having DNS resolution problems that you want to investigate,  there are other better methods. However you first need to read and understand the relevant RFCs. You need to understand concepts like primaries & secondaries, zone-transfers, recursive queries and when disabled/refused, authoritative and non-authoritative.

There is a wonderful book called ["TCP Illustrated, Volume 1" by Stevens](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Protocols-APC/dp/0201633469). Chapter 14 covers DNS. If you truly want to understand DNS, there is probably no better place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was the most exhaustive, I will definitely read the book you recommended, to better understand the protocol tcp and the dns.

Answer (score 2):

No. The DNS gathers its information table from two sources:

- Static information recorded directly at the server.
- Information received from other DNS servers (there is a hierarchy of servers that control this).

When a DNS server receives a request, it simply checks in its internal information table and if the requested DNS name exists it responds with the corresponding IP address without checking if it really matches in real life.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS 'system' is a one-way information table to convert the 'name' to an IP address. This means that the actual IP address to which a name maps is physically not relevant to the DNS answer.

Therefore, the lookup itself never checks for the resolved IP address (it is not meant to do that). The best bet for a record to be correct is from an [Authoritative Name server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Authoritative_name_server) where the mapping has been configured manually. Other servers will get this mapping from such authoritative servers, etc.

For a deep-dive on DNS start from [the DNS Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).